# How to attach a button to the circuit board on a key fob?

Tags: button

I have a power lock key fob for my Subaru where the unlock button has detached from the circuit board. I would like to try to re-attach it, but I am not sure about the right method. Is there some sort of special glue that I should use? It does not look soldered.

Here's the photo of what the circuit board looks like:

[image]

Any additional advice for this repair would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you get a good 10x eye-piece and examine the solder joints on either side?  Board flex and excess finger force can make the solder brittle and break with a smaller than hair-line crack. Reflowing the solder with a <1.5 mm soldering tip is possible with <=1mm wire solder using same eye-piece for this delicate work.  There should be at least 1 or 2 pads on either side to make the switch connect. Heat time ought to be limited to about 3 seconds.  Contacts are something like this one https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/e-switch/TL3315NF100Q/EG4620TR-ND/1870394

Comment: It is soldered, the pads at the unpopulated SW3 on the left show the arrangement. A fine tipped soldering iron is needed, there won't be much of the pad or lead accessible, it would have been originally soldered by reflowing - heating the entire board in an oven to met the solder paste on the pad.

Comment: This is repairable, but it's probably not a good first project - see if you can find someone with a bit of experience to do it, as a mistake could lead to needing to buy a new one, and most likely it will have to be an original for which the dealership absurdly overcharges.